# Vertex generation doesn't exist ...?

Tags: magento2, error, setup-di-compile

Magento 2.2.4, php7.

I' ve been having this error when I try to switch to production and when i try to di:compile;

> Source class \Vertex for \Vertex\Mapper generation does not exist.

No errors in logs , any idea please? 
[image]

Exception trace:

> () at
>   /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:185
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass() at
>   /home/website/public_
>   html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:112
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass() at
>   /home/website/public_html/ve
>   ndor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:180
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass() at
>   /home/website/public_
>   html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:112
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass() at
>   /home/website/public_html/ve
>   ndor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php:35
>   Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load() at n/a:n/a
>   spl_autoload_call() at n/a:n/a class_exists() at
>   /home/website/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Cod
>   e/Scanner/PhpScanner.php:269

Comment: Remove Var/Generation folder

Comment: And compile again

Comment: @AdityaShah doesn't work

Comment: Are you using vanilla Magento  2.2.4?

Comment: @AdityaShah yes community

Comment: Yeah just checked git, reply them on git about confirming the issue.

Answer (score 6):

It's happening because of the Redis cache, run these commands to flush it and try again.

```
redis-cli -n 0 flushall
php -r "echo opcache_reset();"
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```